# Portaudio opens stream but no sound at all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, win-universal-app, portaudio, asio

My unity project includes an unmanaged dll that links to portaudio dll which I've built, everything is configured and built for x86_x64 architecture. My unmanaged dll uses portaudio to open an ASIO audio stream.
I want to build it as Universal Windows Build.

The problem is: a standalone build of unity project works properly on windows 10, also Unity editor works fine, but when I build a Universal Windows Build I get a working application but without sound at all. Logs show that portaudio opens stream successfully and gets all properties of the ASIO driver, which in my case is ASIO4ALL, however when I call `PaAsio_ShowControlPanel()` it opens ASIO4ALL's settings window, but shows that it sees no hardware devices at all, as opposed to listing them when running the same method in a standalone build.

I tried enabling mic permission in unity, visual studio and windows settings.
I also tried running everything as admin, did not work.

Debug output I got when building the generated visual studio 2019 solution included those lines:
`Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDD17BD759 (KernelBase.dll) in MyApp.exe WinRT originate error - 0x80004005  'The window has already been destroyed.'.`

`onecoreuapdriversmobilepcsensorsconvergenceapiwinrtpublicinternalsensorserver.cpp(74)Windows.Devices.Sensors.dll!00007FFD7C3A2E23 (caller 00007FFD7C3EDA61) ReturnHr(3) tid(4a70) 80070490 Element not found.`